# How to serialize and persist a scrapy Request for later use?

Tags: scrapy

I'm writing a downloader middleware able to reschedule any request to be recrawled *n* days later. To give you a rough idea, here is what the request to be rescheduled would look like:

```py
Request(
   url,
   headers={...},
   meta={
      'schedule_recrawl_on': <timestamp>
   },
   dont_filter=False,
   callback=self.parse_item
)
```

My idea is to serialize the request with pickle, persist it somewhere, then have this requests deserialized and injected into the scheduler some time after.

However serializing with pickle isn't easy because the object is referencing an external method `callback=self.parse_item` which is defined on the spider class.

There is a warning about this in [the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#request-serialization) but no clear solution.

Has anyone solved a similar issue? maybe using another serialization principal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Request.to_dict()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.to_dict) method and [request_from_dict()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.utils.request.request_from_dict%5D) function, to serialize and deserialize a Scrapy requests. You pass the spider as argument, when deserializing.

Comment: Can you help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73389010/8519380