# Drop requests that include query string in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I've come across a complicated case.


My problem is that sometimes I have links like `https://sitename.com/path2/?param1=value1&param2=value2` and for me, query string is not important and I want to Drop it from requests.

I mean this part of the url:
`?param1=value1&param2=value2`

After a day of research, I realized that this should be done in the middlewares.py file (Downloader Middleware) ([Source](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)). Because **requests** and receipts in **Scrapy** go through this path.

I tried to write a code so that the requests and answers are without query string, but I did not succeed.

My code does not drop requests that include query string.

middlewares.py:

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner

class CleanUrlAgentDownloaderMiddleware:

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        url_query_cleaner(response.url)
        return response

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        url_query_cleaner(request.url)
```

How can I release these requests using the w3lib.url library or using Python codes? And don't enter Scrapy?

Just to let you know that I set my class in the `settings.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since strings are immutable, your code will not change the anything in the requests. for your code to work you have to do

```py
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner

class CleanUrlAgentDownloaderMiddleware:
    # No need for process response since it will have the same 
    # url as the request

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if "?" in request.url:
            return request.replace(url=url_query_cleaner(request.url))
```

alternately, if you want to ignore requests that have queries in their url you can do

```py
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from urllib.parse import urlparse

class IgnoreQueryRequestMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if urlparse(request.url).query:
            raise IgnoreRequest
```

Comment: It gives me an error.: raise AttributeError(msg)
AttributeError: Request.url is not modifiable, use Request.replace() instead

Comment: @Sardar sorry i forgot about that. i updated the answer

Comment: thank you. This makes the link clean and Scrapy crawls that link.
How to make the url request with the query string be ignored? Can this be done with dropitem? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?highlight=dropitem#dropitem

Comment: if you want to ignore request that has query you can raise IgnoreRequest in middleware https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?highlight=dropitem#ignorerequest

Comment: thanks, Is it possible for you to help me how to use IgnoreRequest?

Comment: i added an example to the answer :)

Comment: It was great, thanks @zaki98 :) , There is a challenge. Some addresses naturally have a question mark and are not query string. For example: "https://example.com/why-should-we-drink-water?" do we have a solution for this case?

Comment: Can this be implemented with the w3lib.url library?

Comment: Yes you can use `urlib.parse.urlparse` but idk if it's the best tool for this i will edit the post to add it

Comment: I really thank you, Is it possible to do this with the w3lib.url library? Because it is installed by default in Scrapy. But the urlib.parse library is not installed.

Comment: i just checked the docs for W3lib.url and there doesn't seem to be a function for that. isn't urllib installed by default ?

Comment: It can be done with the help of from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner , but how to convert it to Boolean to use in the condition?

Comment: for example: url_query_cleaner("example.com/why-should-we-drink-water?")

Comment: Parsel and urlib.parse.urlparse library is installed but W3lib.url apparently does not have it according to this document https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#things-that-are-good-to-know. I may be wrong.

Comment: i think you can do something like this but i wouldn't recommend 

`>>> url = "example.com/why-should-we-drink-water?".strip("?")`

`>>> len(url) != len(url_query_cleaner(url))`